# VS Code code auto autocomplete highlighting

Tags: visual-studio-code, autocomplete

When in VS Code I use auto completion the selected text appears with the highlighted cursor placement. This highlighting prevents VS Code from offering further suggestions.

[image]

How can I disable this highlighting? I want to be able to use autocomplete one after another without having to hit ESC to quit highlighting.

VS Code 1.44.0

Answer (score 6):

The question was already answered by @Anton Solomin.Let me shed more light on it.
Your problem is VS code auto-suggestion is not working when text is highlighted.

Below is the example of issue as you have mentioned in your question.

[Issue screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vjT5.png)

**Reason>** Some of your code snippet is preventing quick suggestion by VS code.
**Solution>** Just tell VS code that don't disable quick suggestion if some snippets askes you to do it.

**How to implement solution>**

1. Go to VScode settings page
2. In settings search bar type `editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions`
3. Uncheck `Controls whether an active snippet prevents quick suggestion`
4. Now your VS code auto suggestion should work.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

// Controls whether an active snippet prevents quick suggestions.
"editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions": true,

Answer (score -1):

add `editor.occurrencesHighlight` in the config file.

for more detail https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/5351#event-982256414

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it doesn't seem to solve tthe issue

Comment: `editor.occurrencesHighlight` is an option that highlights the same semantic symbols across the file. It's not what the author was looking for.